# WAS 6 steps to follow to support MQ 7 features

Tags: java, websphere

I have problem with EAR module deployed in WAS6.

To support the MQ 7 features in my App. I follow the below steps:

1. Put Class loader policy as PARENT_LAST.
2. Placed all MQ 7 related jars in the root of EAR.

EAR contains Web module.  When I try to start the application, I got following exception:

> javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: Can't get definitions factory from context.
>           at org.apache.struts.taglib.tiles.InsertTag.processDefinitionName(InsertTag.java:575)
>           at org.apache.struts.taglib.tiles.InsertTag.createTagHandler(InsertTag.java:474)
>           at org.apache.struts.taglib.tiles.InsertTag.doStartTag(InsertTag.java:436)
>           at com.ibm._jsp._home._jspx_meth_tiles_insert_0(_home.java:106)
>           at com.ibm._jsp._home._jspService(_home.java:81)

The War contains the following jars.

xstream-1.3.1.jar,xercesImpl.jar, xalan.jar,struts.jar, standard.jar,commons-validator.jar, commons-net-1.4.0.jar, commons-fileupload.jar, commons-digester.jar, commons-collections.jar, commons-beanutils.jar,resolver.jar,jstl.jar, jfreechart-1.0.2.jar, jcommon-1.0.5.jar, jaxen-full.jar, jakarta-oro.jar.

EAR contains the following Jars,
com.ibm.mqjms.jar, com.ibm.mq.jmqi.jar, com.ibm.mq.jar, com.ibm.mq.headers.jar, com.ibm.mq.commonservices.jar,log4j.jar,dhbcore.jar.

And I set the class-path attribute in my Manifest file of the WAR with log4j.jar

Please anyone suggest me how Websphere's classloading policy works for where I went wrong.

Karthik

Comment: I'd rather open a ticket with IBM... sure this problem relates to MQ?

Comment: No this is with the class loader policy.  I confused with when web module will be loaded while start the app.

Comment: FYI Websphere 6 goes end of life this year

Answer (score 0):

Some time ago I did something similiar. I wanted to use a specific version of a library which was already used within the WebSphere Application Server. That is the reason why you have to put your libraries in the EAR file and set the application server to PARENT_LAST class loader order.

Correct me if I am wrong, but you also have to specify your custom MQ client libraries in Manifest of your WAR file. You only mentioned Log4J. It should look somehting like this:

```
Class-Path: com.ibm.mqjms.jar com.ibm.mq.jmqi.jar [...] log4j.jar
```

Anyway, you can always check what libraries are in the Classpath of you application if you log into the *Integrated Solutions Console* (aka *Admin Console*) and check the *Troubleshooting* section. There is a classloader viewer. Just click yourself through the tree and check which library path are mentioned and which you would expect.

Finally, as Dylan already mentioned in his comment: WebSphere Application Server version 6.1 runs out of support September 30, 2012. :)